# How to create custom title bar on a TPanel with minimize & maximize options using Delphi XE3 Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am creating  a GUI for a chat application. i am using Tlayouts like a layout for main login page then a separate layout for displaying usernames and a third layout for the chat box. inside the chat layout i had a tpanel . i need to provide it full form like functionality so that i can be minimzed,maxmized ,and also can be moved across the screen.

Any help that i found uptill now is that i can write wm_syscommand messages but i am facing diffculty using its perform function (undeclared identifier error despite i used controls in uses clause) in delphi-xe3.

Comment: If you're trying to mix VCL units with FireMonkey you're in for one hell of a difficult time.

Comment: Better to create a custom style for your panel with minimize/maximize buttons and then show/hide the panel as appropriate.